Azure Table Storage SDK: Continuation Token Not Working, Fetches Same Data Repeatedly
I am using microsoft/azure/storage-table v1.1 SDK in PHP to fetch entities from my Azure Table. My objective is to retrieve all entities. There are over 2000. When you retrieve entities Azure will return a maximum of 1000 results. You need to use the continuation token to handle pagination. However, the code I'm using keeps fetching the same data and showing the same token. The do-while loop executes infinitely, instead of exiting at the break statement. Here is my code:
try {
    $tableClient = self::connect();
    $options = new QueryEntitiesOptions();

    do {
        $result = $tableClient->queryEntities($table, $filter, $options);
        $entities = $result->getEntities();
        
        // Process entities
        foreach ($entities as $entity) {
            // store entities in an array or process them
            $history[] = $entity;
        }

        // Get the continuation token
        $continuationToken = $result->getContinuationToken();

        // If a continuation token exists, set it for the next query
        if ($continuationToken) {
            $options->setContinuationToken($continuationToken);
        } else {
            break;  // No more data, break the loop
        }

    } while (true);

} catch (ServiceException $e) {
    echo $e->getCode() . ": " . $e->getMessage();
}


Be aware that the Azure SDK for PHP reached end-of-life in 2021 and is no longer published nor supported by Microsoft.  We do not recommend using it.

@dram95Check if the provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?

@Venkatesan It does not help. It must be done using PHP SDK not curl method

But, SDK is not supported by Microsoft as know as already mentioned by jesse Squire.


My objective is to retrieve all entities. There are over 2000. When you retrieve entities Azure will return a maximum of 1000 results. You need to use the continuation token to handle pagination.

I followed this MS-Document:
You can use the below code to get all entities using request(curl) method with Azure SAS token.
Code:
<?php

class HttpResponseData
{
    public $code;
    public $data;
    public $message;
    public $nextPartitionKey;
    public $nextRowKey;
    public $entityCount;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->code = 408; 
        $this->data = '';
        $this->message = '';
        $this->nextPartitionKey = '';
        $this->nextRowKey = '';
        $this->entityCount = 0;
    }
}

class ODataInvoker
{
    public static function invokeForOData($method, $storageAccountName, $tableName, $sasToken, $id = null)
    {
        $response = new HttpResponseData();

        try {
            $url = "https://$storageAccountName.table.core.windows.net/$tableName";
            if (!empty($id)) {
                $url .= "/$id";
            }
            $url .= $sasToken;

            $allData = '';

            while (true) {
                $ch = curl_init($url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                    'Content-Type: application/json',
                    'Accept: application/json;odata=nometadata'
                ));

                $responseStr = curl_exec($ch);
                $headerSize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
                $headers = substr($responseStr, 0, $headerSize);
                $body = substr($responseStr, $headerSize);

                $response->code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

                $nextPartitionKey = '';
                $nextRowKey = '';
                foreach (explode("\n", $headers) as $header) {
                    if (strpos($header, 'x-ms-continuation-NextPartitionKey') !== false) {
                        $nextPartitionKey = trim(explode(':', $header)[1]);
                    } elseif (strpos($header, 'x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey') !== false) {
                        $nextRowKey = trim(explode(':', $header)[1]);
                    }
                }

                $allData .= $body;

                // Parse JSON to count entities
                $json = json_decode($body, true);
                if (isset($json['value'])) {
                    $response->entityCount += count($json['value']);
                }

                // Update the next partition and row keys
                $response->nextPartitionKey = $nextPartitionKey;
                $response->nextRowKey = $nextRowKey;

                // Check if there are more pages of results
                if (empty($nextPartitionKey) && empty($nextRowKey)) {
                    break;
                }

                
                $url .= "&NextPartitionKey=$nextPartitionKey&NextRowKey=$nextRowKey";
            }

            $response->data = $allData;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $response->message = $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $response;
    }
}

$storageAccountName = 'xxxx';
$tableName = 'xxx3';
$sasToken = 'xxxxx';

$response = ODataInvoker::invokeForOData('GET', $storageAccountName, $tableName, $sasToken);

echo "Response Code: " . $response->code . "\n";
echo "Response Data: " . $response->data . "\n";
echo "Entity Count: " . $response->entityCount . "\n";
echo "Next Partition Key: " . $response->nextPartitionKey . "\n";
echo "Next Row Key: " . $response->nextRowKey . "\n";
if (!empty($response->message)) {
    echo "Error Message: " . $response->message . "\n";
}

The above code makes an HTTP request to Azure Table Storage using the curl library, retrieves data, and parses the response to extract the HTTP status code, entity count, and pagination keys. It uses a HttpResponseData class to hold the response data and an ODataInvoker class with a static method invokeForOData to make the HTTP request.
If Next Partition Key and Next Row Key were empty, the above code executed and returns all entities.
Output:
:"Entity991"},{"PartitionKey":"9","RowKey":"992","Timestamp":"2024-09-30T04:16:31.8189123Z","Name":"Entity992"},{"PartitionKey":"9","RowKey":"993","Timestamp":"2024-09-30T04:16:31.8189123Z","Name":"Entity993"},{"PartitionKey":"9","RowKey":"994","Timestamp":"2024-09-30T04:16:31.8189123Z","Name":"Entity994"},{"PartitionKey":"9","RowKey":"995","Timestamp":"2024-09-30T04:16:31.8189123Z","Name":"Entity995"},{"PartitionKey":"9","RowKey":"996","Timestamp":"2024-09-30T04:16:31.8189123Z","Name":"Entity996"},{"PartitionKey":"9","RowKey":"997","Timestamp":"2024-09-30T04:16:31.8189123Z","Name":"Entity997"},{"PartitionKey":"9","RowKey":"998","Timestamp":"2024-09-30T04:16:31.8189123Z","Name":"Entity998"},{"PartitionKey":"9","RowKey":"999","Timestamp":"2024-09-30T04:16:31.8189123Z","Name":"Entity999"}]}
Entity Count: 2000
Next Partition Key:
Next Row Key:


